# Can ng-model update objects in the model?

Tags: angular, angular2-forms

I am trying to write a data entry with Angular 2 and Typescript, but I have a problem when updating the model.
As I understood only primitive types can be bind to **ng-model**. But in my model I have objects which I want to be updated.
Is there any angular specific way to do it instead of loading the hole object with the changed property which is bind to **ng-model** ?

This is the model:

```
export class Project {
    public id: number;
    private title: string;
    private region: Region;
}
```

This is the Angular Component class:

```
@Component({...})
export class ProjectForm {
    public project: Project;
    public regions: Array<Region>;
}
```

This is the view of the ProjectForm:

```
...
<select id="region" [(ng-model)]="project.region.id">
    <option *ng-for="#region of regions" [value]="region.id">
        {{ region.name }}
    </option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 4):

Yes! Objects' properties can be bound with `ngModel`. See [Plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/R6R5ZebE1G6x2bWoqCgs?p=preview)

Because,

```ts
<input [(ngModel)]="project.region.id" />
```

breaks down to

```ts
<input [ngModel]="project.region.id"  (ngModelChange)="project.region.id = $event" />
```

which is just same as

```ts
<input [value]="project.region.id" (input)="project.region.id = $event.target.value" >
```

---

So, as you can see it's just passing value from one place to another, that value  (Primitive or Not) can be anywhere.

Comment: It might be notable that `?.` (Elvis operator) can't be used for two-way-binding to objects. At least not currently.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer I didn't know that, thanks for sharing :)

Comment: `[ngModel]="project?.region.?id"` works fine but `(ngModelChange)="project?.region.?id = $event"` is not supported.